# Github: Define that only Beta branch can be merged into master branch?

Tags: git, github, branch, restrictions

I want to set som restrictions or somehow define that only the beta branch, and poitentially any "hotfix" branch, can be merged into the master branch. Is this possible in GitHub?

The reason is to avoid accidental pull requests from a feature or development branch into the master branch.
Also, is it possible to have pull requests default to merge into a development branch, rather than default to merge into master?